# Make a new live copy of EE 2.9.2 website to a new server with a new license

Tags: license, ee2.9.2

I am new to EE.
I have a client who has existing **EE 2.9.2** website up and running developed by another developer.

The client wants to make a copy of this site to another server and point a new domain to the new instance. The client is not sure if the site uses core or licensed version of EE, but I cannot see in the header or footer of the site any Core labels so I assume it is a paid version.

I understand that 2 live sites cannot use the same license. The client is ready to buy another license. My questions are:

1. When the client buy the new license is it a problem that we need license for an old version of EE 2.9.2?
2. I can copy the site but how to change the license with the new one?
3. While I update the new copy with the new license, will this affect the 
   original instance in any way?
4. Will the developer/company get some notification that this license is used twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the site easily to one server to another server. As you are new to EE I suggest you to use [Deeploy Helper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) plugin. (For all absolute and relative paths changes, so new site not take URLs and server path of Old site.)

Answer of your questions are as follows:

1. Your new licence, that would be I think `EE 3.5 +` can use as licence key in your `EE V2.9` site. (Although EE 2.x is no longer available and will expired officially in May 2017. [Blog Here](https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-2-retirement-date)) You can still use EE2.9.x version.
2. Licence Key is Hard coded in config file. Go to `system > expressionengine > config > config.php`. Find the variable `$config['license_number']` and replace your new licence with old one.
3. No. Your OLD site and Licence will not affected. Don't worry. :)
4. No. No notifications will come out. (You also authorized to make a copy site in developer server with same licence so you can develop the site or make a site to development use. It is written in Terms and conditions of EE)

**I hope you get all your answers :)**